# Is there a better way to update single items in ngFor Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire

What's working for me:

invoke.directive.ts

```
export class InvokeDirective {

  @Output() invoke = new EventEmitter();
  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.invoke.emit(null);
  }

}
```

posts.component.html

```
<ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let deal of deals | async, index as i"
        (invoke)="getOwnerData(deal.ownerId)">
          {{ deal.title }} <span class="badge bg-primary" style="color: white; float: right;">{{userNamesArray[i]}}</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

posts.component.html

```
getOwnerData(userId : string) {
    this.ownerDoc = this.userFirestore.doc<any>('users/' + userId);
    this.dealOwner = this.ownerDoc.valueChanges();

    this.dealOwner.subscribe(res => {
      //console.log(res)
      this.ownerName = res.name;
      this.userNamesArray.push(res.name)

      console.log(this.userNamesArray)
    })
  }
```

This is working for me but I just want to know if there is a better way. I tried using one value to bind to but it always updated with the last value making them all the same. Your help will be much appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: If you want to improve performance then use `trackByFunction` with ngFor, it will update only that element which were changed.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda will try that out, mate.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda can you please post some code to how I would use trackBy with my current code? I am also fetching data from another collection using an id if you're familiar with angularfire.

Comment: trackby function will only used for ngFor, angular will update only those lists which were changed from array of objects based on index. trackby function will not affect your current code structure. its just used to improve angular rending by updating list which is changed .

Comment: https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5#:~:text=The%20trackBy%20function%20takes%20the,That's%20all.

Comment: Can you share whats inside `deals | async` ?

Comment: I am getting the ownerId from the deals collection to fetch the name for the user from the users collection. That is why I am calling the getOwnerData() function. I just don't see where trackBy would fit in.

Comment: Oh ok just read your other comment. So it improves performance. I wanted to know if there was another way to do what's working at the moment.

Comment: trackBy is not related to angularFire.. if your lists are larger and if you want to improve performance then you can use it. angular fire and trackBy are both different.

Comment: @GaurangDhorda post an answer about trackBy and Ill upvote but not accept as it's not really the answer I am looking for. It's the least I can give you for your time and will definitely keep it in mind. Thanks, mate.

Comment: when will this `(invoke)="getOwnerData(deal.ownerId)"` invoke event occure ?

Comment: To my understanding, it calls after each iteration if that's the right word for it. It's the only way I am able to make this work at the moment. I can store the name in deals collection as well but I am thinking what if the owner updates their name so this is the only solution I can think of now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231604/discussion-between-gaurangdhorda-and-thesamoanppprogrammer).

Comment: Hello, Can You please come to this discussion panel https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231604/discussion-between-gaurangdhorda-and-thesamoanppprogrammer

Comment: I have on solution.. may be thats working for you.. if you are up now, then come to discussion panel. let me explain to you. and figure out that its working for you or not?

Comment: I am up now, time zone of both are different, now if you are free let come to discussion panel, i am there too. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.deals = this.dealsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
     map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data();
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
        })
),
switchMap(ownerDeals =>
   // do this all in parallel (can use concat instead to do one at a time)
      forkJoin(ownerDeals.map(ownerDeal =>
   // create a new observable for each deal
      this.afs.doc<any>(`users/${ownerDeal.ownerId}`).valueChanges().pipe(
   // only take 1 value
    take(1),
   // merge the deal and user info
    map(user => ({
       ...ownerDeal,
       userName: user.name
    }))
     )
   ))
  )
 );
```

all you need is combination of forkeJoin, and switchMap, and update user-name with ownerID and return combine data. so no need to call extra functionality.

Comment: Thank you very much. Will definitely buy you a coffee when I get paid. You're a bloody legend mate.

Comment: Thank you.. sure It would be so helpful to me too!!